# Notepad++ Trying to add a new line after ONLY the 5th space in each line

Tags: notepad++

Example link but i cant figure how to do it for me.. https://superuser.com/questions/1087902/notepad-trying-to-add-a-character-after-only-the-first-space-in-each-line

short story: i have a long line with different characters and i think only method is after 5 space to make a new line "enter" i hope you can help me.. example situation:

```
bkasdmandrilla 123 vls inlloagribizvvaclog12om V#&quot;log$567 bkasdmandrillapp1hsa 123 vls asd1inovausv1om dyVUIKm-xPPqLFQzCm9RJQ
```

after i add the commands in notepad++ to look like this:

```
bkasdmandrilla 123 vls inlloagribizvvaclog12om V#&quot;log$567
bkasdmandrillapp1hsa 123 vls asd1inovausv1om dyVUIKm-xPPqLFQzCm9RJQ
```

a little help? have like 1-2-3k lines to manual if dont exist a method.. :( i hope exist a magic.

NEW msg: i have multiple texts with diferent large/small text but alwasys will be 5 space where i need to make a new line. i hope the magic exist.. and big sorry for my bad english. (and yes on my original file i have just 1 line with big big text and exactly after 5 space i need to add a new line to them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:\S+\h+){4}\S+\K\h+`
- Replace with: `\n` OR `\r\n` depending on platform
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
    (?:             # non capture group
        \S+           # 1 or more non space
        \h+           # 1 or more horizontal space
    ){4}            # end group, must appear 4 times
    \S+             # 1 or more non space
    \K              # forget all we have seeen until this position
    \h+             # 1 or more horizontal space
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No magic, the find/replace regex example could go like this:

[image]

The regex, explained:

Find: `((\d+ ){5})`

```
The first and last (  ) captures everything matched inside as a group (to use with replace)
Inside, the (\d+ ){5} pattern:
(\d+ ) matches 1 or more digits followed by a single space
{5}    match the digits-followed-by-a-space pattern, repeated 5 times.
```

Replace: `\1\n`

```
\1  the group match of the five digits-followed-by-a-space pattern (from the find)
\n  a newline
```

Note that will leave a trailing space before the newlines in the replacement, as seen in the image. However, the `Macro` menu has a `Trim Trailing and save` option that can be used to remove those.

Comment: asd asasd adasd asdasdasd asdasdasdasd vdasdvas adsadasd 513513 asdadsasdasd 513513asdad 11 12 13 14 15 ... i have on my notepad++ a file like this and your magic dont work :( a little ajust to work please? :(.. and yes i try your magic on 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 and work but on my real file dont..

Comment: The `example situation` in the question only had a list of numbers. Please edit the question above to add an expanded example with a few lines from the file as they are now, and how it should look afterwards. Put both in a formatted section like was done with the output numbers. Will be later today before I can check again.

Comment: ok i edit  my  question because i here i dont have full acces to add code etc (and ye you are right my simple example was with only with numbers but i was sure will work.. sorry was my mistake and ty so much for doing this for me man. and sorry also for my bad english.. )

Comment: If the answer provided by **Toto** works for you, then accept his answer, for he is sharper with regex than I.